# Twilio Chat : reactjs -- issues with function access

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twilio

I am new to reactjs - and looking to gain access to the Twilio chat feature.

I've done an npm install on this module.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-chat

---

The documentation says:

Client instantiation looks as follows:

`Twilio.Chat.Client.create(token).then(client => {
    // Use client
});`

or, using async/await syntax:

`let client = await Twilio.Chat.Client.create(token);
// Use client`

---

/// Old code
I am reconfiguring javascript that was sitting on a codeignitor base. This function worked.

```
"chatClient = new Twilio.Chat.Client(data.token)"
```

---

/// New code

```
import Chat from 'twilio-chat'
```

-- so I've tried something like this first

```
chatClient = new Chat.Client(data.token)
```

then something like

```
chatClient = Chat.Client(data.token)
```

When I do these console logs..I get the following

```
    console.log('Twilio>', Chat)
```

it shows

```
 Twilio>  function Client(token, options) {
            (0, _classCallCheck3.default)(this, Client);

           var _this = (0, _possibleConstructorReturn3.default)(this, (Client.__proto__ || (0, _getPrototypeOf2.default)(Cl…
```

- if I delve into this

  ```
  console.log('Twilio-->Client', Chat.Client)
  ```

it shows

```
Twilio-->Client undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

`twilio-chat` exports the client and as you can see from your first `console.log` it is indeed the `Client` constructor function (class). You have to invoke it like this:

```
chatClient = new Chat(data.token)
```

Note that `import X from 'module'` uses the default export of the `module` and assigns it to the name `X`, it is no indication of which export is used and is just like any other name you'd use for a variable. See [MDN - import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) for the syntax.

Comment: that got me past the first issue -- but then this "getUserChannels()" is not found
 chatClient.getUserChannels().then(createOrJoinChannel)

Comment: https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/0.12.0/docs/Client.html#getUserChannels__anchor

Comment: There is no `getUserChannels` function on `Client`. You linked outdated docs (`0.12.0`). The latest published version is `1.0.2` ([documentation](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/1.0.2/docs/Client.html)).

Comment: right -- yeah the code from the old base is out of date

Comment: Ok so @Michael Jungo --- would I just call chatClient.channels and do the then -- chatClient.channels.then(createOrJoinChannel)

Comment: `.channels` is a map, not a promise. From the documentation it looks like you would want to use [`getSubscribedChannels()`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/1.0.2/docs/Client.html#getSubscribedChannels), so it would be `chatClient.getSubscribedChannels().then(createOrJoinChannel)`.